# Can I have a better explanation of what part of toggle() has been kept in Jquery 2.0?

Tags: jquery

> **.toggle(function, function, ... ) removed**
>
> This is the "click an element to run the specified functions"
>   signature of .toggle(). It should not be confused with the "change the
>   ***visibility of an element" of .toggle() which is not deprecated.*** The
>   former is being removed to reduce confusion and improve the potential
>   for modularity in the library. The jQuery Migrate plugin can be used
>   to restore the functionality.

Is there a use case of what part of toggle() in use that works vs a use case where it does not work?

Comment: The toggle function that toggles visibility, as in show and hide, is still there, while the toggle function that accepts two functions and toggles them on click is entirely removed.

Comment: "toggles them on click" == "alternately invokes one and then the other (repeat)"

Comment: I think its clear based on `'visibility of an element" of .toggle() which is not deprecated'` toggle can be used for toggling showing/hiding elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// this is not deprecated
$("#theanchor").click(function(){
    $("#thediv").toggle(); // shows or hides the div
});

// this is deprecated
$("#theanchor").toggle(function(){
    $("#thediv").hide();
},function(){
    $("#thediv").show();
});
```

As you can see, the former is far cleaner anyway. In most cases where the old .toggle is used, .click can be used in a cleaner way.

Comment: _"the former is far cleaner anyway"_ - Well... "cleaner" depends on what you're trying to do. Note that the click event binding version that's been removed let you specify as many functions as you liked to be executed in sequence, not just two functions.